# Can't build with vsce package

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, npm, package, vscode-extensions

So I get this error while trying to build a vscode extension by running

```
vsce package
```

I get the following error:

```
error An unexpected error occurred: "/path/package.json: Unexpected token ']', ...\" },
      ],
      \"\"... is not valid JSON".
```

I've tried reviewing the json, running through json linters..
I've updated npm..
reinstalled and cleaned cache several times..
No success so far :(

Here's the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "Wandy",
  "version": "1.1.2",
  "description": "description",
  "displayName": "Wandy",
  "icon": "resources/extensionIcon.png",
  "license": "MIT",
  "categories": [
    "Other"
  ],
  "keywords": [
    "wandy"
  ],
  "activationEvents": [
    "onView:Wandy.chatView",
    "onCommand:Wandy.ask",
    "onCommand:Wandy.explain"
  ],
  "main": "./dist/extension.js",
  "contributes": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "command": "Wandy.ask",
        "title": "Wandy → Chat Assistance"
      },
      {
        "command": "Wandy.explain",
        "title": "Wandy → Explain Selection"
      }
    ],
    "menus": {
      "editor/context": [
        {
          "command": "Wandy.ask",
          "when": "editorTextFocus",
          "group": "Wandy-menu-group@1"
        },
        {
          "command": "Wandy.explain",
          "when": "editorHasSelection",
          "group": "Wandy-menu-group@2"
        }
      ],
      "commandPalette": [
        {
          "command": "Wandy.ask"
        },
        {
          "command": "Wandy.explain",
          "when": "editorHasSelection"
        }
      ]
    },
    "viewsContainers": {
      "activitybar": [
        {
          "id": "Wandy",
          "title": "Wandy",
          "icon": "./resources/icon.png"
        }
      ]
    },
    "views": {
      "Wandy": [
        {
          "type": "webview",
          "id": "Wandy.chatView",
          "name": "Wandy"
        }
      ]
    },
    "configuration": {
      "title": "Wandy",
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "Wandy.apiKey": {
          "type": "string",
          "markdownDescription": "markdownDescription",
          "order": 0
        },
        "Wandy.model": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "default"
          ],
          "default": "default",
          "description": "description",
          "order": 1
        },
        "Wandy.pasteOnClick": {
          "readOnly": true,
          "type": "boolean",
          "default": true,
          "description": "description",
          "order": 2
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "vscode:prepublish": "yarn run package",
    "compile": "webpack",
    "watch": "webpack --watch",
    "package": "webpack --mode production --devtool hidden-source-map",
    "compile-tests": "tsc -p . --outDir out",
    "watch-tests": "tsc -p . -w --outDir out",
    "pretest": "yarn run compile-tests && yarn run compile && yarn run lint",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext ts",
    "test": "node ./out/test/runTest.js",
    "update-package-lock": "npm install --package-lock-only"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "openai": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/glob": "^8.1.0",
    "@types/mocha": "^10.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^20.3.0",
    "@types/vscode": "^1.73.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.59.9",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.59.9",
    "@vscode/test-electron": "^2.3.2",
    "eslint": "^8.42.0",
    "glob": "^10.2.7",
    "mocha": "^10.2.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.3",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "vscode": "^1.73.0"
  }
}
```

any ideas on how to fix it?
thanks!

packaging a vs code extension using

```
vsce package
```

Comment: delete parts of the `package.json` to find the line/section it complains about